# Proof A × (B ∩ C) = (A × B) ∩ (A × C)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is this proof enough?

A × (B ∩ C) = (A × B) ∩ (A × C)

L = A × (B ∩ C) =

= {(a, b) | a ∈ A, b ∈ (B ∩ C)} =

= {(a, b) | a ∈ A ∧ (b ∈ B ∧ b ∈ C)} =

= {(a, b) | (a ∈ A ∧ b ∈ B) ∧ (a ∈ A ∧ b ∈ C)}

R = (A × B) ∩ (A × C) =

= {(a, b) | (a, b) ∈ (A × B) ∧ (a, b) ∈ (A × C)} =

= {(a, b) | (a ∈ A ∧ b ∈ B) ∧ (a ∈ A ∧ b ∈ C)}

L = R

Comment: yes this is enough

Comment: It's a bit of an interesting way of phrasing your proof. Usually one would prove $A\times (B\cap C) \subseteq (A\times B) \cap (A\times C)$ and vice-versa by supposing an arbitrary $x\in A\times (B\cap C)$ and then showing that $x\in (A\times B)\cap (A\times C)$ (and again, vice-versa), although what you've done seems sufficient to me.

Comment: I think it is easier to prove the equality using double inclusion. But your proof works as fine.

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for typesetting math on this site.